# Selectable country list

Tags: angular

I would like to display a selectable country list by typing. I have tried it with the package angular-countries and added the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" list="countrylist" class="form-control" ng-model="userDoc.country">
<ngcountries></ngcountries>
```

but I get the error

> 'ngcountries' is not a known element:

Is that because angular-countries is for AngularJS only? I am using Angular 8.

Comment: Did you add the import to app.module.ts?

Comment: @a2441918 no, I didn't. How do I import it?

Comment: `angular-countries` is an AngularJS library - not an Angular library. It is not compatible with Angular 8.

Comment: @MS_AU good to know about that, thank you. Is there something similar for Angular 8?

Comment: Yes, its an Angularjs library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular-countries` is a AngularJS library - not an Angular library. It is not compatible with Angular 8.

A similar library for Angular 2+ does exist: https://github.com/Paldom/angular2-countrypicker#readme